# Send filled out PDF Form to Uploadlink

Tags: hyperref, url

I've created a PDF form for a survey. Because of anonymity I need a Submit-Button which sends the filled out pdf (or fdf) to an uploadlink and automatically "puts it in there".

Here is an MWE in which the pdf opens the link:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

    Was ist Fortschritt?\\
        \def\DefaultHeightofText{5pt}
        \mbox{\TextField[width=\linewidth, height=4em, bordercolor={black}, multiline=true, format={setBackground(Color.red)}]{}}

\begin{tabular}{c | c }
\TextField[default=www.google.com,bordercolor=,name=link1,width=8cm,charsize=10pt]{} & 
\PushButton[
        onclick={
            app.launchURL(this.getField("link1").value);
        },
        name=hlink1,
        readonly=false, bordercolor=, width=2cm, charsize=10pt
    ]{Submit}
\end{tabular}   

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

I work with seafile where I can create an uploadlink. The picture shows how the page from the uploadlink looks like. I am now looking for a way in which the pdf document not only opens the link but also sends "itself up there" without needing to search for it manually with the buttons. If that's possible without me needing to contact seafile or so than that would help me a lot! :)

Picture from the upload link:

[image]